# Weird HyperV Ethernet in Taskmanager after Version 20H2 update

Tags: networking, hyper-v

today I noticed in my Taskmanager some new entries of HyperV Virtual Network. I never turned Hyper V on, that entry is still on "off" in the Windows Features List, and I dont use any virtual machines or vpns.
I think it might be because of the newest big Windows Update 20H2, or maybe even a virus.
What do you think?

Thank you in advance.

[HyperV in Feature List turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxNTS.png)

[Taskmanager entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOpu3.png)

Edit: To clarify I never used any Virtual Maschines or HyperV, so its a little scary to see it pop up from itself

Answer (score 0):

The entry is related to Hyper-V and/or Sandbox. Use of either one at some point will create that entry.

I have a Windows Insider Machine and I have the vEthernet Entries as you do.

I have this machine here which is a VMware Machine and I have the VMware network devices, but no Hyper-V devices because I cannot run Hyper-V or Sandbox on this machine.

It is definitely not a virus, malware or OS corruption.

This machine is 20H2 and the Insider machine is 21H something.

It is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I never used any VM and I run native Windows- so thats the thing I worry about.

Comment: It is probably because of the way Windows sets up and would either be for a Hyper-V setup or replaced by a VMware or Vbox setup - in other words a place holder. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Kinematikk - Windows Sandbox is only installed by the end user.  If you are the only user on the machine, then you must have enabled it, without realizing you did so.  Since Hyper-V is not installed the only feature that could be installed is Windows Sandbox.  **Hyper-V also is enabled by default.**  I can confirm that the Virtual Adapter does not exist if Hyper-V and Sandbox are disabled on 20H2

Comment: Agree with  Ramhound,@Kinematikk please check if you installed Windows sandbox in the windows feature. If yes, just uncheck Sandbox and then these virtual adapter should be gone.